# How to pass data from one Javascript controller file to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, model-view-controller

So, the situation I have gotten myself seems to be a little complicated but I'm hoping there is a simple solution to it.

I have two Javascript controller files, one called `rootPageClient.js` and another called `findPollClient.js`. There is also a file called `ajax-functions.js` which basically contains two functions to route the `ajax` calls to the right route. The routes and the get and post method functions are contained in the `index.js` file. The file structure is shown below

```
Root
  Common
    ajax-functions.js
  Controllers
    findPollClient.js
    rootPageClient.js
  routes
    index.js
```

I have a specific piece of data in the `rootPageClient.js` file that I need passed through to the `findPollClient.js` file. All calls are routed through the `ajax-functions.js` file to the requested route in `index.js`. 
I have figured out that I need to call the same route in the `index.js` file from both controller files in the order that I want to pass the files from and to. But, I'm not quite sure how to do this. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a service and save the data inside the service. Have the service injected in both the controllers. Whenever you change some data in service in one of the controllers, it will retain when you look it up in other controller. This is because services and factories are singletons, so they are the right place to store application state and access it anywhere you want.

Comment: Hey, sorry, I'm going to need a little more explanation than that. What exactly is a service? I should probably note that I am not using Angular JS and have no idea how to use it. I am writing most of my code for this in JavaScript using the jQuery library